# Align text to the bottom in MPDF

Tags: html, css, mpdf

How do I align the texts in the table header to the bottom in this MPDF file?

[image: align text]

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-weight: bold;color: black;width:100%;">
<thead>
<tr text-rotate="90">
<th text-rotate="0" style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:16px;width:20%;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;color: black;vertical-align: bottom;">SUBJECTS </th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;color: black;font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; width:40px; text-align:center;">CA1 10% </th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;color: black;font-weight: bold;font-size:15px; width:40px; text-align:center;"> CA2 10% </th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I can't seem to move the texts in the header to the bottom. I have tried vertical-align= bottom but no luck.

Comment: If you want to align them to the bottom why do you use `text-align:center;` ? :) i mean... use text-align left ( in your case )

Comment: text-align left moves it to the left, not bottom

Comment: text-align left on the ones that are rotated. Not sure how '  text-rotate ' works ( as it's not a css property ) but if it works the same as `transform: rotate()` then text-align left should work.

Comment: text-rotate is what works on MPDF

Comment: Then use `text-align: left` as what [@MihaiT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6441124/mihai-t) said. It's logical if text-align left moves it to the left, but since you rotate it `90 degrees` **anti-clockwise**, left text-align will make it bottom text-align.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the follwing code to your `th`

```
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(-180deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like that , Hope it will help you.

```css
th span{
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: rotate(180deg);

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-weight: bold;color: black;width:100%;">
<thead>
<tr text-rotate="90">
<th text-rotate="0" style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:16px;width:20%;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;color: black;vertical-align: bottom;"><span>SUBJECTS</span> </th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;color: black;font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; width:40px; text-align:center;"><span>CA1 10% </span></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;color: black;font-weight: bold;font-size:15px; width:40px; text-align:center;"><span> CA2 10% </span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed "vertical-align: bottom" directly to the  and it worked. I don't know why it didn't work before.